# minitest-rails : Test controller with full url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, custom-routes

I want to test my controllers with minitest but :
- I use custom routing only
- I don't use named routes

I have some routes like this :

```
scope "administration" do
  get '', to: 'administration#index'
  get 'user/:id/update/', to: 'user#update'
end

scope "front" do
  get 'user/show', to: 'user#show'
end
```

Is there a way to test a request with full url (get "/administration/user/2/update/" for example)?

Comment: I would give it a try and update your post with any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller tests need the controller and actions to be known to the router, but you invoke the action directly without using the path. If you want to pass paths then you want to use Integration tests instead. You don't need to use named routes for either.